# How can I return an error message and status code for a method with return type list<some sObject>?

Tags: apex

For the below code how can I return an error message instead of an empty List when it there is an Exception?

```
@HttpGet
global static List<Lead> someFunctionName() {
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
try{
String sLID = RestContext.request.params.get('Id');

List<Lead> searchLead = [Some query];

return searchLead;
} catch (Exception e) {
req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());

List<Lead> myList = new List<Lead>();
return myList;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a custom exception class,
Either create a separate exception class that extends Exception class

```
global class MyCustomException extends Exception{
   global static void genricException(){
     throw new MyCustomException('Something went wrong!');
    }
}
```

or create an inner class like,

```
global class MyClass{

global List<SObject> getRecordList(){
List<SObject> sObjList = [......];
 try{
  return sObjList;
 }
 catch(Exception ex){
  throw new MyCustomException(ex.getMessage());
 }
}

private class MyCustomException extends Exception{} //our custom Exception class which extends behavior & inherits all methods of this class.
}
```

You can also generate custom exception messages too...

```
throw new MyCustomException('Service returned empty response');
```

When we say `throw new MyCustomException` this will generate an exception & will block further execution of the code. The Constructor of the class takes a string argument which is the message of the exception. `Service returned empty response` or `ex.getMessage()` is the exception string we want to throw.

You can read more about CustomExceptions [here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm)

Comment: I am new to this. Could you please explain in a little more detail.

Comment: Is that clear now?